# Class "Laravel\Octane\Octane" not found

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-octane

I'm trying to run Laravel Octane in Docker. I'm using FrankenPHP. When it starts, in log I'm getting lots of:

```bash
ERROR  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Laravel\Octane\Octane" not found in /app/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/bootstrap.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/frankenphp-worker.php(19): require()
#1 /app/public/frankenphp-worker.php(3): require('...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /app/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/bootstrap.php on line 24
```

and in a minute container restarts.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM dunglas/frankenphp

ENV SERVER_NAME=mysite.com

RUN install-php-extensions pcntl

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git zip unzip nano && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists//*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql opcache

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY . /app

RUN mv /app/.env.prod /app/.env

RUN composer install \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-dev \
    --optimize-autoloader

RUN php artisan key:generate  \
    && php artisan config:clear \
    && php artisan config:cache \
    && php artisan route:cache \
    && php artisan view:cache \
    && php artisan event:cache \
    && php artisan storage:link

ARG USER=laravel

RUN addgroup -gid 1000 ${USER} && useradd -ms /bin/bash -g 1000 ${USER}

RUN setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/local/bin/frankenphp

RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /data/caddy && chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /config/caddy

USER ${USER}

WORKDIR /app
```

And here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    image: "my_username/my_image:latest"
    entrypoint: php artisan octane:frankenphp
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: mysite.com
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
```

If I run to check if Octane class is there:

```bash
sudo docker exec app_1 ls -l /app/vendor/laravel/octane/src/Octane.php
```

the file is there.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/octane#frankenphp-via-laravel-sail - you've done `php artisan octane:install --server=frankenphp`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not using FrankenPHP binary, I'm getting FrankenPHP image from docker hub. In my Dockerfile:  FROM dunglas/frankenphp. And in my .env I have: OCTANE_SERVER=frankenphp

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line in Dockerfile:

```
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

Investigating further I found that variables_order in php.ini causes that error. It was

```
variables_order="GPCS";
```

I changed it to:

```
variables_order="EGPCS";
```

and it works. Of course this is not ideal solution, I reported this to FrankenPHP and they promised to fix it.

For more information, please check GitHub issue:
https://github.com/dunglas/frankenphp/issues/541